# Build a java app that asks the user to input a series of grades between 0-100

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Im extremely new at Java programming and my professor asked us to write a program that can:

Show each grade by the letter. (Ex: A, B, C, D, F)
Show the Minimum & Average grade of the class
Show the number of people who passed the exam (70+ is passing)

I have been trying to use arrays and if else statements to solve this but Im not making much progress. Can you guys please help me out?

I know I'm not good at coding, but here is something I am trying.

I also would like to incorporate if else statements in my code to make things simpler.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    double[] grades = new double[10];
    int sum

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Number of students: " + grades.length);

    for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++)
    {
      System.out.print ("Enter number " + (index+1) + ": ");
      grades[index] = scan.nextDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Removed the JavaScript tag since your question is about _Java_.

Comment: Hints: Your array of doubles should be created once you know the # of students (it's size is the # of students, of course). Then, perform the loops for the grades to be set as you read input from the user. Next, the last part is just a matter of getting the values you are looking for (# of passed students, average, etc...) by looping through the grades array. Also, you can do most everything you want in one loop after you fill the grades array if you wanted..

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you're asking us to just do the rest of this for you, you're out of luck. If you are stuck on a particular part, be more specific and we'll try to help. It looks like you have a good start so far.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask you for the answer. I just wanted to know how I should write the code to find the things I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the minimum value is done by using a `for` loop just like your current one and using:

```
min = Math.min(min, grades[index]);
```

---

The average can be found just by finding the sum inside the loop:

```
sum += grades[index];
```

And then divide by the number of values.

---

The number of grades 70+ can be found with an `if` statement inside the loop:

```
if (grades[index] >= 70) {
    numPassing++;
}
```

---

Each of these operations can also be done using [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) from Java 8:

```
double min = Arrays.stream(grades).min().orElse(0.0);
double avg = Arrays.stream(grades).average().orElse(0.0);
long numPassing = Arrays.stream(grades).filter(grade -> grade >= 70).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I modified the code a bit, plus I didn't used any functionalities provided in java so that you can understand the flow control and logic as being a newbie to java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    double[] marks = new double[10];
    char[] grades=new char[10];
    int[] numGradeStudent={0,0,0,0,0};
    int min=0,avg=0,minIndex=0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Number of students: " + grades.length);

for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++)
{
    //Taking  marks then applying grades and counting no.  of students 
  System.out.print ("Enter number " + (index+1) + ": ");
  marks[index] = scan.nextDouble();
  if(marks[index]>90)
     grades[index]='A';
  if(marks[index]>75 && marks[index]<=90)
     grades[index]='B';  
  if(marks[index]>65 && marks[index]<=75)
     grades[index]='C';  
  if(marks[index]>55 && marks[index]<=64)
     grades[index]='D'; 
  else
     grades[index]='E';

 //Setting up graded students down from here
 if(grades[index]=='A')
     numGradeStudent[0]++;
 if(grades[index]=='B')
     numGradeStudent[1]++;
 if(grades[index]=='C')
     numGradeStudent[2]++;
 if(grades[index]=='D')
     numGradeStudent[3]++;
 if(grades[index]=='E')
     numGradeStudent[4]++;
}
min=numGradeStudent[0];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(numGradeStudent[i]<min){
        min=numGradeStudent[i];
        minIndex=i;
    }

}
System.out.println("Min grade of class is:"+ grades[minIndex]);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(marks[i]>70)
        System.out.println("Student "+(i+1)+" passed.");
}
```

}
}